# RemoteIO Audio Problem - simulator = good - device= bad

Tags: iphone, c, core-audio, audiounit

O.K , so I'm using core audio to extract audio from 10 different sample sources and then mixing them together in my callback function.

It works perfect in the simulator and all was well. I ran into trouble however when I tried to run it on an 4.2 iphone device.

If I mix 2 audio files in the callback everything is ok.
If I mix 5 or 6 audio files the audio plays but after a short amount of time the audio degrades and eventually no audio will go to the speakers. (The callback does not stop).

If I try to mix 10 audio files the callback runs but no audio at all comes out.

It's almost like the callback is running out of time which might explain the case where I mix 5 or 6 but would not explain the last case mixing 10 audio sources where no audio at all is played.

I'm not sure if the following has any bearing but this message always prints to console when I'm debugging. Could this be some indication as to what the problem is?

```
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 1
continue
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
```

** set up my callback**

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Callback setup & control

- (void) setupCallback

{
    OSStatus status;


    // Describe audio component
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    // Get component
    AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // Get audio units
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &audioUnit);

    UInt32 flag = 1;
    // Enable IO for playback
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &flag, 
                                  sizeof(flag));

    //Apply format
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                                  kOutputBus, 
                                  &stereoStreamFormat, 
                                  sizeof(stereoStreamFormat));

    // Set up the playback  callback
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback; //!!****assignment from incompatible pointer warning here *****!!!!!!
    //set the reference to "self" this becomes *inRefCon in the playback callback
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &callbackStruct, 
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));

    // Initialise
    status = AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit); // error check this status


}
```

**The CallBack**

```
static OSStatus playbackCallback (

                                     void                        *inRefCon,      // A pointer to a struct containing the complete audio data 
                                     //    to play, as well as state information such as the  
                                     //    first sample to play on this invocation of the callback.
                                     AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags, // Unused here. When generating audio, use ioActionFlags to indicate silence 
                                     //    between sounds; for silence, also memset the ioData buffers to 0.
                                      AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,   // Unused here.
                                     UInt32                      inBusNumber,    // The mixer unit input bus that is requesting some new
                                     //        frames of audio data to play.
                                     UInt32                      inNumberFrames, // The number of frames of audio to provide to the buffer(s)
                                     //        pointed to by the ioData parameter.
                                     AudioBufferList             *ioData         // On output, the audio data to play. The callback's primary 
                                     //        responsibility is to fill the buffer(s) in the 
                                     //        AudioBufferList.
                                     ) {


    Engine *remoteIOplayer = (Engine *)inRefCon;
    AudioUnitSampleType *outSamplesChannelLeft;
    AudioUnitSampleType *outSamplesChannelRight;

    outSamplesChannelLeft                 = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
     outSamplesChannelRight  = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

    int thetime =0;
    thetime=remoteIOplayer.sampletime;


        for (int frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < inNumberFrames; ++frameNumber)
        {
            // get NextPacket returns a 32 bit value, one frame.
            AudioUnitSampleType *suml=0;
            AudioUnitSampleType *sumr=0;

            //NSLog (@"frame number -  %i", frameNumber);
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)

            {


                AudioUnitSampleType valuetoaddl=0;
                AudioUnitSampleType valuetoaddr=0;


                //valuetoadd = [remoteIOplayer getSample:j ];
                valuetoaddl = [remoteIOplayer getNonInterleavedSample:j currenttime:thetime channel:0 ];
                //valuetoaddl = [remoteIOplayer getSample:j];
                valuetoaddr = [remoteIOplayer getNonInterleavedSample:j currenttime:thetime channel:1 ];

                suml = suml+(valuetoaddl/10);
                sumr = sumr+(valuetoaddr/10);

            }


            outSamplesChannelLeft[frameNumber]=(AudioUnitSampleType) suml;
            outSamplesChannelRight[frameNumber]=(AudioUnitSampleType) sumr;


            remoteIOplayer.sampletime +=1;


        }

    return noErr;
}
```

**My audio fetching function**

```
-(AudioUnitSampleType) getNonInterleavedSample:(int) index currenttime:(int)time channel:(int)ch;

{

    AudioUnitSampleType returnvalue= 0;

    soundStruct snd=soundStructArray[index];    
    UInt64 sn= snd.frameCount;  
    UInt64 st=sampletime;
    UInt64 read= (UInt64)(st%sn);


    if(ch==0)
    {
        if (snd.sendvalue==1) {
            returnvalue = snd.audioDataLeft[read];

        }else {
            returnvalue=0;
        }

    }else if(ch==1)

    {
        if (snd.sendvalue==1) {
        returnvalue = snd.audioDataRight[read];
        }else {
            returnvalue=0;
        }

        soundStructArray[index].sampleNumber=read;
    }


    if(soundStructArray[index].sampleNumber >soundStructArray[index].frameCount)
    {
        soundStructArray[index].sampleNumber=0;

    }

    return returnvalue;


}
```

**EDIT 1**

In response to @andre I changed my callback to the following but it still did not help.

```
static OSStatus playbackCallback (

                                     void                        *inRefCon,      // A pointer to a struct containing the complete audio data 
                                     //    to play, as well as state information such as the  
                                     //    first sample to play on this invocation of the callback.
                                     AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags, // Unused here. When generating audio, use ioActionFlags to indicate silence 
                                     //    between sounds; for silence, also memset the ioData buffers to 0.
                                      AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,   // Unused here.
                                     UInt32                      inBusNumber,    // The mixer unit input bus that is requesting some new
                                     //        frames of audio data to play.
                                     UInt32                      inNumberFrames, // The number of frames of audio to provide to the buffer(s)
                                     //        pointed to by the ioData parameter.
                                     AudioBufferList             *ioData         // On output, the audio data to play. The callback's primary 
                                     //        responsibility is to fill the buffer(s) in the 
                                     //        AudioBufferList.
                                     ) {


    Engine *remoteIOplayer = (Engine *)inRefCon;
    AudioUnitSampleType *outSamplesChannelLeft;
    AudioUnitSampleType *outSamplesChannelRight;

    outSamplesChannelLeft                 = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
     outSamplesChannelRight  = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

    int thetime =0;
    thetime=remoteIOplayer.sampletime;


        for (int frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < inNumberFrames; ++frameNumber)
        {
            // get NextPacket returns a 32 bit value, one frame.
            AudioUnitSampleType suml=0;
            AudioUnitSampleType sumr=0;

            //NSLog (@"frame number -  %i", frameNumber);
            for(int j=0;j<16;j++)

            {



                soundStruct snd=remoteIOplayer->soundStructArray[j];
                UInt64 sn= snd.frameCount;  
                UInt64 st=remoteIOplayer.sampletime;
                UInt64 read= (UInt64)(st%sn);

                suml+=  snd.audioDataLeft[read];
                suml+= snd.audioDataRight[read];


            }


            outSamplesChannelLeft[frameNumber]=(AudioUnitSampleType) suml;
            outSamplesChannelRight[frameNumber]=(AudioUnitSampleType) sumr;


            remoteIOplayer.sampletime +=1;


        }

    return noErr;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Like Andre said, it's best not to have any Objective-C function calls in the callback.  You should also change your inputProcRefCon to a C-Struct instead of an Objective-C object.
2. Also, it looks like you might be going frame-by-frame 'manually' copying the data into the buffer.  Instead, use memcopy to copy a chunk of data in.
3. Also, I'm pretty sure you're not doing disk I/O in the callback, but if you are you shouldn't do that either.

Comment: I finally got this to work on a device. I had been passing a class reference to the callback. Instead I now pass struct pointers of audio data. I've removed all obj-c code. It's amazing the impact on performance obj-c has. I'm going to look into the memcopy suggestion also to see if I can improve further.

Comment: I had a question for you. The callback as I see requires you to pass it frames for i < n frames. I guess this is "frame by frame". would copying a chunk work by removing the i< n frames loops?

Comment: Just a quick note -- in my experience, frame-by-frame copy and memcpy take about the same amount of time.  I have benchmarked this extensively in the past, since I do a lot of audio work.  I have found that both algorithms essentially take about the same amount of time, as the bottleneck is memory I/O speed, not the CPU.

Comment: Oh, and of course, never start optimizing your code unless you have your profiler handy. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, try not to use Objective-C function calls in your RemoteIO Callback. They will slow it down. Try to move your "getNonInterleavedSample" function in the Callback using C structures for accessing the audio data.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're CPU-limited; the simulator is much more powerful in terms of processing speed than the various devices.

The callback probably can't keep up with the frequency at which it's being called.

EDIT: Could you "precompute" the mixing (doing it ahead of time or in another thread), so that it's already been mixed when the callback fires, and the callback has less work to do?

Comment: I had an icnkling it might be something like that but I for the life of me cant find out where to change the number of frames per callback to confirm

Comment: I don't believe you can control the number of frames that the callback is asked to fill (inNumberFrames).  In theory, you have to be prepared for scenarios where that could vary (in practice, I've always seen that value be 512).